# toggle visiblity of options in a dropdown list on the selection in another dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to know how to toggle visiblity of options in a dropdown list on the basis of what we select in another dropdown.

eg: consider a dropdown named **continent** with options:

```
  asia, europe, america, africa.
```

now consider another dropdown named **country** with countries as options.
What i require is that if i select **asia** from dropdown **continent** only the countries in **asia** must be visible in the dropdown **country**.

I am not able to make this work. pls help me.

Comment: http://www.bitrepository.com/dynamic-dependant-dropdown-list-us-states-counties.html

Comment: AliRıza Adıyahşi: It works thanks........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another example, simpler than the link (that I also +1d) in the comments

http://jsfiddle.net/joevallender/Y6Rjz/1/

Code below

HTML

```
<label for="continent">Continent</label>
<select id="continent">
    <option value=""> -- Please select -- </option>
    <option value="asia">Asia</option>
    <option value="europe">Europe</option>
</select>

<label for="country">Country</label>
<select id="country"></select>
```

JS

```
var data = {
    asia: [
         'china',
         'japan'
    ],
    europe: [
         'france',
         'germany'
    ]
}

$('#continent').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    var list = data[value];
    $('#country').empty();
    $('#country').append(new Option(' -- Please select -- ',''));
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
       $('#country').append(new Option(capitaliseFirstLetter(list[i]),list[i]))   
    }
})

// Helper from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript
function capitaliseFirstLetter(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: not exact the same but it is an start :)

http://jsfiddle.net/Diabl0570/M82JF/4/

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in a more generic, non-jquery solution, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/XH6vh/)